# Power of matrix using diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

First one

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2& 3\\5
& 1
\end{pmatrix}^{20}$$

Second one
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4&0& 0\\0
& 3&0\\2 &0&2
\end{pmatrix}^{20}$$

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0& 0\\0
& 1&0\\1 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0& 0\\0
& 1&0\\-1 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have some difficult to solve this problem.
For the first one, the characteristic equation is $(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)-15=\lambda^2-3\lambda-13=0$ that $\lambda$ is $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{61}}2$ is it right?

For the second one, I find $P$ and $P^{-1}$, but multiplication of $P^{-1}AP$ is not diagonal.
Is there any case that $A$ cannot be represented as a diagonal but power of $A$ can be calculated?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! As your question stands right now, it is a bit hard to understand. Please try to tidy it up using MathJax so that we may help you. For your second question, it will always be possible to calculate the power of any matrix by simply multiplying it with itself many times, but for a large matrix, it is very tedious.

Comment: Thanks, I will tidy it up in some minutes!

Comment: For the second one, I think multiplication of p inverse, A, and p should be a diagonal but it is not. Is it all right?

Comment: How did you find $P$ without also finding the eigenvalues of $A$? If you don’t get a diagonal matrix from $P^{-1}AP$, then either your $P$ is wrong or you’ve made a mistake calculating that product.

Comment: I found it by finding eigenvalues but didn’t write because it was difficult to draw lots of matrixes in mobile. I’m sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ has distinct eigenvalues, it must be diagonalizable.

\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}  \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but why is it different to calculate A multiplicate P first from P inverse multiplicate A?

Comment: Oh I made some mistake for matrix multiplication. I soved it thank you!!

Comment: @4charwon if this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the tick next to answer. this will let others know that the question has been answered.

Comment: I accepted it thanks!